# Alinear botones al final de un div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo un formulario y necesito que los botones queden a la altura de los `<select>`. **Necesito que siempre estén pegado al borde de abajo del div que lo contiene** Esto hará que siempre queden alineados con los `<select>`, esta característica tanto en versiones mobile como desktop.

```css
.btn-bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20% !important;
}

.btn-bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20% !important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
        Razón social
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
      </label>
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona una razón social</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
        Sucursal
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
      </label>
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona una sucursal</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
        Departamento
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
      </label>
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <option value="NEW_CAR">Autos nuevos</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-left">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Buscar
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-right">
        <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Limpiar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Le agregué ese código de CSS. En el viewport sm de bootstrap 4 se ve bien, se empareja justo como lo necesito, pero se desbarata cuando es un móvil.

Me gustaría buscar una solución limpia con CSS, sin espacios, paddings o margins al tanteo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bueno deberías quitar la clase denominada [**`clearfix`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/clearfix/) ya que esta esta encaminada a:

> Easily clear floats by adding .clearfix to the parent element.

Es decir (no es traducción):

> Nos ayuda a que una etiqueta padre pueda contener a los hijos que tenga y estos tengan la naturaleza flotante, para que de esta manera evitemos queden por fuera de la antes mencionada.

**NOTA**

> En la medida de lo posible deberías evitar el uso de **`!important`**, justo [aquí](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-4/#importance) puedes leer mas al respecto sobre su uso.

**EJEMPLO**

```html
      <style>
        .container {
          background-color: red;
          border: solid 1px;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        .child {
          float: left;
          background-color: tomato;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section class="container">
      <article class="child">Uno</article>
      <article class="child">Dos</article>
    </section>
```

Como los hijos del `div` son flotantes debemos indicar que el *overflow* del padre sea automático y entonces sea capaz de contener a sus elementos internos.

Sin embargo al estar usando como muestras la última versión de [**Bootstrap**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/) esta misma incluye el uso de las funcionalidades de flexbox mediante clases como:

- **`d-flex`**
- **`justify-content-around`**

Entonces deberías proceder:

- Elimina la clase *clearfix*
- Agrega las propieades arriba listadas
- Antes de que ocurra el ajuste visual por efecto del *responsive* aplicaremos lo siguiente
- Anulamos el margin por defecto y con una pequeña regla CSS ajustamos la altura de los botones con respecto de los **`select`** de esta manera:

Regla css

```
  .d-flex { 
    margin-top: 1.9em;
  }
```

- Posterior cuando la maquetación se ajusta por efecto de las *media queries* solo deberás revisar que clase conviene mas agregar de flexbox para ajustar el acomodo de los botones:

  - **`justify-content-center`** (Los dejaría al centro sobre el eje principal)
  - **`justify-content-around`** (para distribuir a los elementos con un espacio a los lados y entre ellos)
  - **`justify-content-between`** (para distribuir a los elementos con un espacio entre ellos)

Completo:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .d-flex { 
        margin-top: 1.9em;
      }
    
    </style>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
            Razón social
            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
          </label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona una razón social</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
            Sucursal
            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
          </label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona una sucursal</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
            Departamento
            <span class="text-danger">*</span>
          </label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option value="NEW_CAR">Autos nuevos</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-left">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Buscar
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-right">
            <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Limpiar
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Le quité la clase `clearfix` al `div` padre de los botones "Buscar" y "Limpiar". Como estás usando `bootstrap` use sus clases `CSS` predefinidas, al `div` le apliqué las clases:

Nota: La clase `CSS` `.top-40-percent` es personalizada.

- `.d-flex, justify-content-between` -> Para que los botones estén en cada extremo del `div`.
- `.position-relative, .top-40-percent` -> Para poner el `div` en posición relativa y mover el `div` un 40% de la distancia del `div` padre.
- `w-100` -> Para que el `div` ocupe el 100% del espacio.

Espero haberlo explicado bien.

```css
.top-40-percent {
    top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
                        Razón social
                        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona una razón social</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
                        Sucursal
                        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona una sucursal</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
                        Departamento
                        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="NEW_CAR">Autos nuevos</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100 position-relative top-40-percent">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Buscar
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                        <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Limpiar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo este código, espero te ayude. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<main>
  <div class="container-">
    <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
        <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
                    Razón social
                    <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
        <select class="custom-select">
          <option value="0" selected disabled>-- Seleccionar --</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
        <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
                    Sucursal
                    <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
        <select class="custom-select">
          <option value="0" selected disabled>-- Seleccionar --</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
        <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
                    Departamento
                    <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
        <select class="custom-select">
          <option value="NEW_CAR">-- Seleccionar --</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-left">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Buscar
                    </button>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-right">
                        <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Limpiar
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para usar una solución de CSS, sin necesitar de `bootstrap` o librerías de terceros, puedes usar [CSS Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

```css
.row-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;

    align-content: center;
}

.centered-row {
    justify-content: center;
}

.centered-row > * {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <div class="row-container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
                        Razón social
                        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona una razón social</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
                        Sucursal
                        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona una sucursal</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fs7 m-0 text-secondary">
                        Departamento
                        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="NEW_CAR">Autos nuevos</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
    
      </div>

      <div class="row centered-row">

        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-left">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Buscar
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-right">
            <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Limpiar
        </button>

      </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Básicamente se trata de dos clases, `row-container` y `row`.
`row-container` es una "lista" vertical de filas. Usa la propiedad `flex` con dirección `column`, para hacerla vertical y alinea cada contenido dentro aprovechando el máximo espacio (`space-between`), de este modo los `buttons` siempre quedan pegados abajo de todo.

`row` es una "lista" horizontal. Usa la propiedad `flex` con dirección `row` para hacerla horizontal y alinea el contenido usando todo el espacio repartido (`space-around`).

Hice una tercera clase (`centered-row`) para la `row` que contiene los botones, que básicamente, en vez de aprovechar todo el espacio, centra el contenido en el medio y pone `10px` de margen entre botón y botón.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Usando manualmente los `flexbox` se tiene mucho más control. Tal y como se usan en el ejemplo que puse, son 3 líneas de CSS y permite escalabilidad. Además, se pidió una solución limpia en CSS.

Answer (score 0):

ojala te ayude el codigo, saludos

```css
.btn-bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20% !important;
}

.btn-bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20% !important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Selecciona una razón social

```
  </div>
    
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona una sucursal</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
    
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <option value="NEW_CAR">Autos nuevos</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-left">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Buscar
      </button>          
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="clearfix">
      
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-bottom-right">
        <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i> Limpiar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```